# "criteria for" VS "standards for"

Tags: word-difference

> 1. The Guideline sets out **criteria** for evaluating the performance of officials.
> 2. The Guideline sets out **standards** for evaluating the performance of officials.

In daily use, does **criteria** overlap with **standards**? If a guideline list a number of  factors to rate how an official perform, do we call these factors criteria or standards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would instead say that "standards" is a *subset* of "criteria", as it refers to some criteria that have been *accepted as standard*, either by the general public or by some authority.

For the most part (meaning I can't think of any exceptions, but it's possible) "criteria" can be used in any context where you can use "standards", but not the other way around.  In some contexts, however, "standards" may sound better, given the additional meaning.  For example:

> The court outlined new **standards** for laying out electoral districts to ensure greater fairness.

Here the use of "standards" emphasizes that these criteria are defined by an *official body*, and meant to be applied in a *consistent* manner.  "Criteria" would be less authoritative.